# What is thermophoresis?

Tags: molecules, molecular-dynamics, brownian-motion

I read wikipedia article and I saw a bad youtube presentation on [thermophoresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermophoresis), however I don't have a clear insight about the subject. I assume the forces are basically Brownian molecular forces involved. I believe the principle of the thermophoresis phenomenon is simple, yet I am not sure. Can you elaborate please? Without equations, no need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Phoresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoresis) is a suffix that means migration.

[Thermophoresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermophoresis) is simply the result of responses to temperature gradients by motile particles in a mixture.  Particles larger than the [mean free path](http://aerosol.ees.ufl.edu/aerosol_trans/section06_b.html) of molecules of the gas in which they are suspended, are impacted by gas molecules and driven toward less energetic regions.

[Thermophoretic force](http://aerosol.ees.ufl.edu/Thermophoresis/section02.html) is the net force given to suspended particles by more energetic molecules against less energetic molecules.  Thus, suspended particles tend to migrate toward colder regions and away from hotter regions.  This effect generally is confined to a 1 mm or less boundary layer around the source of heat.  For example, if you hold a hot rod in a cloud of smoke, you should observe a thin particle-free layer of air surrounding the rod.